# Unknown size of struct, when accessing fields in tvbuff_t struct

Tags: c, ssh, wireshark

I am currently debugging Wireshark to add a decryption plugin for SSH.
I found out the ssh packet data is stored in a struct tvbuff_t. But when I want to access the fields of this struct I get the error: "error C2036: "tvbuff_t *": Unknown Size".

How can I access the fields of this struct?

```
static int  
ssh_dissect_ssh2(tvbuff_t *tvb, packet_info *pinfo,
        struct ssh_flow_data *global_data,
        int offset, proto_tree *tree, int is_response,
        gboolean *need_desegmentation)  
{  
    g_print("data: %02x\`n", tvb[5]);  
}
```

Comment: What is `tvbuff_t`? How would you expect `printf` to understand that type? And considering the error you get, it seems that `tvbuff_t` is an [*opaque data type*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type) that you should not directly access anyway.

Comment: Tvbuff_t is defined here: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsar_html/structtvbuff.html
And as such I thought that Wireshark should understand what the struct contains. I mean it uses it later on, to dissect the data.

Comment: If you follow the link to the [header file](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsar_html/tvbuff-int_8h_source.html) (which indicates that it's an internal or private header file with the `int` part in the name) you will see the header comment that contains the text "Structures that most TVB users should not be accessing directly." So it's indeed a private structure, you should not access it directly in any way.

Comment: Besides, if you want the fifth byte of the package then `tvb[5]` is really not how you access it. Perhaps you should take a few steps back, get a couple of books, and refresh your C knowledge.

Comment: ok. Thanks. Didn't saw that